# Replace part of XML node value

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to replace a part of a xml node value with another value. For example, I've this node in my xml:

```
<eerste_kwartier>naam leeg</eerste_kwartier>
```

or for example:

```
<eerste_kwartier>leeg leeg</eerste_kwartier>
```

In the first example I want to replace the 'leeg' value with something else. In the second I only want to replace the first 'leeg' value with something else. Any ideas how I should do this?

Thanks in advance,

Jan Thiemen

Comment: Right. And what have you tried? You have two options here: change it manually in PHP by extracting the node via `xpath()`, or applying some XSLT to it. The former would be easier in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can achieve this with PHP using DOM.

Given an XML format in a string like this:

```
    $xml = <<<EOX
<root>    
  <eerste_kwartier>naam leeg</eerste_kwartier>
  <eerste_kwartier>leeg leeg</eerste_kwartier>
</root>
EOX;
```

you could do what follows:

### 1 - Use PHP and DOM

Using DOM you can obtain a list of elements having the same tag name with the getElementsByTagName() method, walking that list and applying text transformations you prefer.

Example:

```
// Load source XML
$xmlObj = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xmlObj->loadXML($xml);

// Obtain interesting nodes into a node list object
$nodeList = $xmlObj->getElementsByTagName('eerste_kwartier');

// Prepare destination XML object
$xmlObjResult = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$rootElement = $xmlObjResult->createElement("root");

// Walk node list
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
  $tmp = $nodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
  // Use regular expressions for greater flexibility in selecting text to replace
  $tmp = preg_replace('/naam/', 'leeg', $tmp);
  // Prepare destination element
  $eerste_kwartier = $xmlObjResult->createElement("eerste_kwartier");
  $cdata = $xmlObjResult->createCDATASection($tmp);
  $eerste_kwartier->appendChild($cdata);
  $rootElement->appendChild($eerste_kwartier);
}

// Append root element to the document
$xmlObjResult->appendChild($rootElement);

// Enjoy your XML
echo $xmlObjResult->saveXML();
```

### 2 - Use PHP and DOMXPath

The example above could be easily changed to use XPath's query() instead of DOM's getElementsByTagName().

So you would do:

```
// Load source XML
$xmlObj = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xmlObj->loadXML($xml);

// Obtain interesting nodes into a node list object
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlObj);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//eerste_kwartier");

// Prepare destination XML object
$xmlObjResult = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$rootElement = $xmlObjResult->createElement("root");

// Walk node list
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
  $tmp = $nodeList->item($i)->nodeValue;
  // Use regular expressions for greater flexibility in selecting text to replace
  $tmp = preg_replace('/naam/', 'leeg', $tmp);
  // Prepare destination element
  $eerste_kwartier = $xmlObjResult->createElement("eerste_kwartier");
  $cdata = $xmlObjResult->createCDATASection($tmp);
  $eerste_kwartier->appendChild($cdata);
  $rootElement->appendChild($eerste_kwartier);
}

// Append root element to the document
$xmlObjResult->appendChild($rootElement);

// Enjoy your XML
echo $xmlObjResult->saveXML();
```

### Conclusions

As you've certainly noticed the two options are quite similar.

If your search within the document resolves into searching for the same tag name I would suggest going with option 1; if your search should be even slighly more articulated than that, I suggest option 2, as XPath has loads of nice weapons to fight XML search-through complexity (a brief introduction to XPath can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), but there's a lot of material available just googling around).

I wouldn't get XSL into the picture, unless you should apply a higher scale and articulated transformation of your content, but just in case: http://htmlite.com/XML008.php (an extremely brief XSLT introduction tutorial, which should tickle your appetite).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class to extract what you need. Here is a working solution:

```
$str = '<eerste_kwartier>naam leeg</eerste_kwartier>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML( $str);
$doc->appendChild( $fragment);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
$node = $xpath->query( '/eerste_kwartier')->item(0);

$text = $doc->createTextNode( $node->textContent);
$node->nodeValue = ''; // Clear out the contents of the tag

// Get the text before and after the replacement
$start = strpos( $text->wholeText, 'leeg');
$before = $text->substringData( 0, $start);
$after = $text->substringData( $start + strlen( 'leeg'), strlen( $text->wholeText));

// Put the text back, minus the replacement, with something else added
$node->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( trim( $before)));
$node->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( "Something Else"));
$node->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $after));

echo htmlentities( $doc->saveXML());
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/X8my8p):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <eerste_kwartier>naam Something Else</eerste_kwartier>
```

For the second test case, it [will output](http://viper-7.com/C0bUVz):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <eerste_kwartier>Something Else leeg</eerste_kwartier>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cant you use str_replace function?

```
$xml = str_replace('<eerste_kwartier>leeg leeg</eerste_kwartier>','<eerste_kwartier>somethingelse leeg</eerste_kwartier>',$xml);
```